# Height of a <div> in a bootstrap form

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have this in a bootstrap form:

Name
      
       "/>

```
 <div class="form-group ">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" for="email">E-mail</label><?php echo @$_SESSION['ctform']['email_error'] ?>
  <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
   <input class="form-control" id="email" name="ct_email" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(@$_SESSION['ctform']['ct_email']) ?>"/>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I cannot define the height of my  and as a result I have a lot of space (200px) between the fields. Any idea how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp   Check This

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this way:

```
var el = document.querySelector(".form-group");
el.style.width = "200px";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
       <?php echo @$_SESSION['ctform']['email_error'] ?>
      <input class="form-control" id="email" name="ct_email" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(@$_SESSION['ctform']['ct_email']) ?>"/>

    </div>
  </form>  
</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FENK34MFH506